# PHP - Setting 200 status code for 403 and 404 Error Document working in localhost but not working in CPanel

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp, cpanel

I am trying to set Custom 403 & 404 page with 200 response code using php method **http_response_code**

It works fine in localhost [XAMP Server] with 200 response code.
But it throws 403 & 404 response instead of 200 in CPanel Hosting.

**.htaccess**

```
Options -Indexes
DirectorySlash Off
DirectoryIndex index.html .index.php index.php

ErrorDocument 403 /response.php
ErrorDocument 404 /response.php
```

**response.php**

```
<?php
http_response_code(200);
?>

<!-- HTML Document -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        Content...
    </head>
    <body>
        Content...
    </body>
</html>
```

**Problem Screenshot:**

[LocalHost Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyMXF.png)

[Cpanel Hosted Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ17d.png)

**Expectation**

Looking for 200 status in Cpanel Hosted Result

Comment: Why should a 404 not be answered with the correct status code?

Comment: Do not do this. For a start it's a great way to get DOSed by search engines because they will repeatedly attempt to index anything that returns a 200.

Comment: Actually I am creating a package which reads content of folder and display as webpage

Comment: If the folder contains any page mentioned in the directory index from htaccess it loads as usual.

Comment: If files mentioned in directory index not found it search for predefined files to generate html - if predefined files found in the directory then generate html & set 403 to 200 else generate page with "content not found" set 403/404 error to 200